# Chebyshev/Taylor polynomial error

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion, chebyshev-polynomials

So i have this equation:

$ y = x^2 * sqrt(1-x^2)$

when i work out the chebyshev polynomials and the taylor polynomials there is an offset of 0.18 between them.

to work out the polynomials i used:

$ T_0 = 1 $

$ T_1 = x $

$ T_2 = 2x^2 - 1$

$ T_3 = 4x^3 - 3x$

$ T_4 = 8x^4 - 8x^2 +1$

the polynomial would now be sum of all:

$sum of  ... a_n *T_n$

now to work out the coefficient i used:

$a_n = \frac{2}{\pi} \int^{1}_{-1} (\frac{f(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}T_n)dx$

$f(x) = x^2 \sqrt{1-x^2}$

so for $T_0 we$ get

$a_0 = \frac{2}{\pi} \int^{1}_{-1} (\frac{x^2 \sqrt{1-x^2}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}T_0)dx$

$a_0 = \frac{2}{\pi} \int^{1}_{-1} (x^2 * (1) )dx$

soving this we get

$a_0 = \frac {4}{7\pi} = 0.1819..$

so that 0.18 is not suppose to be there. without the 0.18, my chebyshev and taylor is almost identical but with it there we can see the shift.

I dont see anything wrong with my work, are we not suppose to include the first term or am i missing something?

Comment: How do you get a factor 7 in the $T_0$ coefficient? $\int_{-1}^1 x^2dx=[\frac13x^3]_{-1}^1=\frac23$, so that $a_0=\frac{4}{3\pi}$. The accumulated constant coefficient is $\frac4{3\pi}(\frac12-\frac15-\frac{13}{35})=\frac2{3\pi}\frac{35-14-26}{35}=-\frac{2}{21\pi}=-0.030315227...$

Comment: oh yes sorry i got 4/3*pi but when you consider the next a2 and a4 the sum of all of them is 4/7pi i am not sure where you got 1/2 - 1/5 - 13/35 from...

Comment: i get 4/3pi - 4/15pi -52/105pi giving 4/7pi

Comment: Note that $\langle T_0,T_0\rangle=\frac2\pi\int_{-1}^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=2$, so that you need to scale the constant coefficient appropriately in the final expression of the partial sum of the series.

Comment: i am kind of confused on how you got that. and how that affects the result

Comment: This happens quite regularly with Fourier series in trigonometric forms, look it up. When you have $f(x)=a_0T_0(x)+a_1T_1(x)+...$, where the component functions are orthogonal, then you get the coefficients as $a_k=\frac{⟨f,T_k⟩}{⟨T_k,T_k⟩}$. For $k>0$, you have $⟨T_k,T_k⟩=1$. You need to divide by 2 somewhere for the $k=0$ term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you expect them to be identical?

- The Taylor polynomial gives the best guess of the function based on value and derivatives at one point,
- the Chebyshev polynomial is the best (given a definition of "good") approximation over the interval

As the function is positive over most of the interval $[-1,1]$, it is not really surprising that the mean over the interval is also positive.

#### Taylor

$$
x^2\sqrt{1-x^2}=x^2(1-\tfrac12x^2-\tfrac18x^4+...)
$$

#### Chebyshev

This can be understood as the Fourier cosine expansion of 
$$
f(\cos(s))=\cos^2s\,|\sin s|
=\frac{a_0}2+a_1\cos(s)+a_2\cos(2s)+...
$$ 
over $[0,\pi]$, inserting $x=\arccos(s)$ into the partial sums. The coefficients are
$$
a_k=\frac2\pi\int_0^\pi f(\cos(s))\cos(ks)\,ds
$$
giving $a_1=a_3=0$ because of odd symmetry around $s=\frac\pi2$ and
\begin{align}
a_0&=\tfrac2\pi[-\tfrac13\cos^3s]_0^\pi=\tfrac4{3\pi}=0.424412,\\
a_2&=\tfrac2\pi[-\tfrac25\cos^5 s+\tfrac13\cos^3s]_0^\pi=\tfrac4{15\pi},\\
a_4&=\tfrac2\pi[-\tfrac87\cos^7 s+\tfrac85\cos^5 s-\tfrac13\cos^3s]_0^\pi=-\tfrac{52}{105\pi}.
\end{align}

[image: plot of function and approximations]

As you can see, the Taylor expansion is extremely good around $x=0$ and far away at the boundaries while the Chebyshev approximation distributes the error more equally over the whole interval.

Comment: i calculated my chebyshev a bit differently but got almost same graph. But the thing is i used the 'first kind chebyshev polynomials' i obtain the  same graph as your but with an offset. my questions is why am i getting this offset of 0.1819 ($4/(7*pi)$). if i take ignore it i get same graph as you.

Comment: Yes, these are exactly the ones I used, $T_n(x)=\cos(n\arccos(x))$. The question is if you used the correct scalar product to compute the coefficients. The correct scalar product makes the $T_n$ orthogonal. How did you compute your coefficients?

Comment: i have updated my questions so you can see how i get the 0.1819... the scalar product is correct because it was given in the question... if i just ignore it my answer seems perfect my it doesnt make sense

Comment: Yes, the scalar product is correct, how you carry out the integration of the square is wrong at some point.